# Want to reactivate the playback feature with the G35 headset. Can't find it

Tags: windows-vista

When I bought my G35 it played back all the sound from the microphone which I liked, then I installed the G35 software which made it dissapear and now I can't find how to reactivate it. I have windows vista 64 bit.

Comment: I love that headset and the voices that you can enable with it. I would post a screenshot and link, but don't have my headset plugged in and I'm away from the puter.

Answer (score 0):

According to Logitech you can achieve this by doing the following:

- Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound
- Select the Recording tab
- Select the G35 microphone
- Click Properties
- Select the Listen tab
- Check the box beside "Listen to this device"
- Click Apply and OK

Comment: That's weird, I can't find any "Listen" tab. I got vista but I don't know if that makes any difference. Could you provide me with the link to where you found that information so I could search for myself?

Comment: I found that windows 7 has a "Listen" tab, but that doesn't help me :P

Answer (score 0):

They have recently updated their software. Make sure that you're downloading and using the latest version.

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/438/5095?section=downloads&bit=&osid=13

Comment: Thanks alot, my problem wasn't fixed inside that program but the program added the changeable settings inside the control panel which allowed me to activate playback. Thanks alot!